# Error módulo Python

Tags: python, funciones, modulos

tengo un problema con este ejercicio de Python alguien sabe porque me da error cuando quiero importar el módulo funciones_matematicas?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y agrega el código y los mensajes como texto.

Comment: Lo siento, pero si has guardado el otro archivo?

Comment: Lo volví a ejecutar de nuevo y funciono el programa no me volvió a dar error no se que abra sido, muchas gracias igual!